# How to print a nested list in Erlang: [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]?

Tags: erlang

I have a list which is similar to [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]] and I need to print it something like this:

```
1
1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

How do I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the list in `L` you can use something like this:

```
lists:foreach(
    fun (L2) ->
        lists:foreach(
            fun(X) -> io:format("~p ", [X]) end,
            L2
        ),
        io:format("~n") end,
    L
).
```

I guess you can optimize a bit on the `io:format` parts.